# `useEffect` not being able to fetch data on component mount

Tags: node.js, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to set an array of objects into `dineIns` after fetching them inside useEffect. What I understood is that there is some kind of delay in receiving the data because the state variable returns an empty array when I log it after fetching the data.

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

function CheckIns() {
  const [dineIns, setDineIns] = useState([]);

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
      const user = jwtDecode(token);
      if (!user) {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        navigate('/login');
      } else {
        async function UserData(user_email) {
          const user_data = await axios
            .get(`/api/users/${user_email}`)
            .then((res) => {
              const info = res.data.reservations;
              setDineIns(info);
              console.log(dineIns);
            });
        }

        UserData(user.email);
      }
    } else {
      navigate('/login');
    }
  }, []);
}
```

What needs to be corrected here to set the state in time?

Comment: Does the dineIns get populated correctly after some time?

Comment: state updates are asynchronous. use another `useEffect` to log the latest result. `useEffect(() => { console.log(dineIns) }, [dineIns])`

Comment: For more details check [this](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value)

Answer (score 0):

set state is an async operation, which log the data after set it, will log the old value.

To ensure that the data set correctly, you can use setState again

```
const info = res.data.reservations
setDineIns(info)
setDineIns(prev => {
  console.log(prev)
  return prev;
})
```

Or you can use effect with `dineIns` dependence.

I think your code works fine.

Comment: "To ensure that the data set correctly, you can use setState again". What do you mean by this statement ?

Comment: set state parameters save the last edit to it, so if you you log inside a set state you will get the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a `Promise` from the `axios` call but you are `await`ing it.
Try to change your code like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    const user = jwtDecode(token);
    if (!user) {
      localStorage.removeItem('token');
      navigate('/login');
    } else {
      async function UserData(user_email) {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/${user_email}`);
          setDineIns(data.reservations);
          console.log(dineIns);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }

      UserData(user.email);
    }
  } else {
    navigate('/login');
  }
}, []);
```